# How do I correctly set up a Linux VM as a gateway to route all traffic through a Wireguard VPN connection?

Tags: iptables, route, gateway, wireguard, nordvpn

I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple of weeks trying to figure out how to set up a Linux VM on a Mac to act both as a NordVPN client and a gateway/router to forward all traffic from certain devices on my LAN through the VPN connection.

My setup:

- My LAN subnet is 192.168.2.0/24.
- I have a Mac Pro running macOS Big Sur 11.6, with Parallels Desktop Pro 17.0.1 installed, and connected to my LAN using wired Ethernet.
- In Parallels, I've set up a Ubuntu 21.04 VM. This VM has two NICs configured - `enp0s5` and `enp0s6`.
- Both VM NICs are bridged to the default wired adapter on the host machine, and both receive an IP from my LAN's DHCP server.
- In the VM, NordVPN is installed and working fine, configured to use Nordlynx (Wireguard) as the protocol.

My intention is to have the VM use `enp0s5` to access the Internet and connect to NordVPN, while using `enp0s6` as an incoming interface to receive traffic from other devices on my LAN (and forward them through the VPN).

So, first I connect to the VPN:

```
$ nordvpn connect us
Connecting to United States #6918 (us6918.nordvpn.com)
You are connected to United States #6918 (us6918.nordvpn.com)!
```

After which my interfaces look like so:

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.76  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        ether 00:1c:42:b9:d5:a3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 120786  bytes 157627189 (157.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17840  bytes 1450595 (1.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.64  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        ether 00:1c:42:59:54:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11342  bytes 3589378 (3.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 277  bytes 77293 (77.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 948  bytes 99424 (99.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 948  bytes 99424 (99.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nordlynx: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.5.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.5.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 39  bytes 14380 (14.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 61  bytes 11396 (11.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here I do a simple speed and connectivity test, and the VPN connection works fine.

OK so now I want to forward all traffic sent to the enp0s6 interface by other devices on my network, through the `nordlynx` interface. So I do:

```
iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface nordlynx -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp0s6 -j ACCEPT
```

I also check to make sure IP forwarding is enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Finally, to test the gateway functionality, on another laptop (a Macbook Pro) on my LAN I configure a static IP and set the the default gateway to be the `enp0s6` IP from my VM (`192.168.2.64`).

Then I try to browse the web from the Macbook - but it doesn't work.

What am I missing or doing wrong? How can I best troubleshoot this?

I tried doing a traceroute from the Macbook Pro to see how far I get, but tracing to any IP outside my local LAN subnet while having the Ubuntu VM set as the default gateway just gets me this:

```
$ traceroute 37.156.192.50
traceroute: findsaddr: write: No such process
```

The routing table on the Linux VM looks like so:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         nordvpn-gw      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 nordlynx
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s5
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp0s6
128.0.0.0       nordvpn-gw      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 nordlynx
unn-138-199-52- _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s5
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s6
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s5
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enp0s6
```

Thankful for any help or advice. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** As per @A.B's comment I also tried simplifying the setup to use only one NIC on the VM, but it made no difference.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I have also configured NordVPN to NOT add any firewall rules.

Comment: Remove any use of enp0s5 and see if it works (ie don't add an IP address on it, don't link it to the bridge, actually just don't create the interface, use a single interface on the same LAN, not two).

Comment: @A.B OK, so tried that now - it did not make a difference. From the Macbook, tried to see how far I get by using traceroute, but it just prints "traceroute: findsaddr: write: No such process" if I traceroute to any address outside my LAN subnet while having the VM set as the default gateway.